Approximating a $f(x, y) = (Ax + a)^T (By + b)$
I'm working with matrices $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{m,n}$ and vectors $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^m$, where $m < n$. I have defined a function
$$
f(x, y) = (Ax + a)^T (By + b).
$$
I want to find matrices $A', B' \in \mathbb{R}^{m-k,n}$ and vectors $a', b' \in \mathbb{R}^{m-k}$ such that the difference
$$
f'(x, y) - f(x, y)
$$
is as small as possible. I'm not particularly focused on any exact metrics for the error; I'm just looking for some methods or ideas to approach this problem.

After expanding,
$$
f(x, y) = x^T A^T B y + x^T A^T b + a^T B y + a^T b,
$$
I thought to apply SVD on $A^T B = U \Sigma V^T$ and use it as follows:
$$
A' = (U \Sigma)^T, \quad B' = V^T,
$$
with reduced $U$, $\Sigma$, and $V$. However, I can’t figure out how to adjust $a, b$ accordingly. I tried setting
$$
a' = V B^T a, \quad b' = \Sigma^{-1} U^T A^T b,
$$
but even with $k = 0$, this doesn’t approximate $f(x, y)$ well. Instead, I get:
$$
x^T A^T B y + x^T A^T b + a^T B y + a^T B V^T \Sigma^{-1} U^T A^T b,
$$
where the last term doesn’t match up.

I would like a method that doesn’t rely on data, but if that's not feasible, would having a sample of $(x, y)$ pairs from the distribution help? How? Thanks, I'm not a mathematician, so any guidance would be appreciated.

I don't see how this can be made well-posed in any sense without specifying what value of $x$ and $y$ matter. Is it a single point? A distribution?
